# How to create and edit gridview at runtime along with adding rows?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a aspx page consisting of a calendar button and a textbox.When we click calendar button then a calendar appears and the date which i select on calendar appears in textbox. Now what i want is to load the data from database according to the date selected and allow the user to edit it.And also i want to enable user to add rows at runtime. Do i need to create grid view at runtime?? Can somebody point me in a direction??

Comment: If you tag this with a language (c#, vb.net, etc.), it will have a lot more activity, and people giving you an answer can know what language to provide it in.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the gridview at runtime. You can define the gridview in the markup without having any data initially. You can set the calendar to autopostback and on the server side, capture the new date selected, grab the data based on that date and bind it to your gridview.

As far as editing the data, Gridviews already provide support for this and the amount of code that you need to write largely depends on how the datasource for the gridview is set up. If you use a SQLdatasource with the appropriate settings you practically don't have to write a single line of code besides the markup (Google: Gridview SQLdatasurce editing ASP.net).